# What does the term 'binding' mean in JS?

Tags: javascript, terminology

Please clarify for me what the term **binding** means in JavaScript. I've started to read the book 'Eloquent JS' and there are lots of occurrences of this word. Does it just mean variable? Here are few examples from the book:

1. So if you know that the property you are interested in is called color, you say value.color. If you want to extract the property named by the value held in the **binding** i, you say value[i].Property names are strings. They can be any string, but the dot notation works only with names that look like valid **binding** names.
2. **Bindings** can also be changeable or constant, but this is separate from the way their values behave. Even though number values don’t change, you can use a let binding to keep track of a changing number by changing the value the **binding** points at. Similarly, though a const **binding** to an object can itself not be changed and will continue to point at the same object, the contents of that object might change.

Comment: It sounds to me like "key value pair" - as in the "binding" occurs between key and value. I'm not sure if there's an official definition of the term "binding" within the context of javascript.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding

Comment: These may be helpful http://webster-dictionary.net/definition/binds , http://webster-dictionary.net/definition/bond

Answer (score 2):

I've found out what it is (in this book in an earlier chapter). Here is the snippet:

> How does a program keep an internal state? How does it remember things? We have seen how to produce new values from old values, but this does not change the old values, and the new value has to be immediately used or it will dissipate again. To catch and hold values, JavaScript provides a thing called a binding, or variable:
>
> ```
> let caught = 5 * 5;
> ```
>
> That’s a second kind of statement. The special word (keyword) `let` indicates that this sentence is going to define a binding. It is followed by the name of the binding and, if we want to immediately give it a value, by an `=` operator and an expression.
>
> The previous statement creates a binding called `caught` and uses it to grab hold of the number that is produced by multiplying 5 by 5.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is a general term to mean that your symbol or variable points to some location in memory. This is also illustrating the principle in JavaScript that even when you declare an object using const, you can still manipulate the properties of that object. Only the reference to the object itself cannot be redefined.

So you can't say myObj = {greeting: "Hello Stack Overflow"} and then myObj = someOtherObj. But you can say myObj.greeting = "Beep Boop"

Comment: This is a hodge-podge of different tangentially related concepts but does not actually answer the question.

Comment: What do you mean hodge podge, I answered that question directly. "Please clarify for me what is term binding mean in JavaScript?", the snippet he links also mentions the fact that this binding can be made with a const declaration and the properties can still be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me clarify. The first question what is a binding:

1. A binding is a symbol, variable, constant, etc. that points to some literal value, or object in memory.
2. In reference to your book, it says:

   ```
   const myObj = { color: blue }; // the property color is defined on this object
   myObj["color"]; // => "blue" The color property can be accessed by passing in a string
   myObj = anotherObj; // not allowed, you declared it with const
   ```

The reference or binding is to the object in memory and that cannot change because you declared this reference with const. But you **can** modify the properties of the object in memory. The object itself is mutable.

Any further discussion of bindings is a discussion on Lexical Scope.